# Processing error with this code

Tags: processing

```java
float speed = 1;
void setup() {
size(400, 300);
}

void draw() {
background(255);
move();
display(); 
}

void move() {
x = x + speed;
if (x > 350) {
speed = 0;
}
}

void display(x,y) {
fill(#FF2121);
translate(x,y);
ellipse(0, 0, 60, 60);
rect(-10, 15, 20, 100);
}
```

Unexpected token: x on "Void display (x,y)"
Basically this program moves the ellipse and rect to other side of the window. is this the right way to do it? or is there any other easy way.

Example 
0 = ellipse 
[] = rect

move to other side of window (speed of 1) and when it hit the edge, both them stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters need types, just like variables do.

```
void display(float x, float y) {
```

Also note that since your `display()` function takes 2 parameters, it's illegal to call it without any parameters, which is what you're doing in your `draw()` function.

Also note that you've never defined the `x` variable, so that's another error.

Please get into the habit of [working in smaller chunks](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) instead of trying to write your whole program all at one time. You've got quite a few errors here, and it's going to be hard to fix one without fixing the others. I recommend starting over with something simpler, and only moving forward when you have something that works.

Comment: i did that before posting here but on draw function, "display()" shows error.

Comment: @DipakMukesh You `display(float x, float y)` function takes two parameters. Calling `display()` without any parameters is an error.

Comment: Thanks sorted, if you can give a tip when blocks hit the edge, how can i send it back to beginning position?

Comment: @DipakMukesh Please see [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).